How does Hardened Scales and Doubling Season interact?
If I have a Hardened Scales and a Doubling Season in play and I play a Aquastrand Spider does it enter with 5 or 6 +1/+1 counters?
So basically is it a case of (2 + 1) * 2 or (2 * 2) + 1?

You get to choose whether it enters with 5 or 6 counters.
The Spider entering is replaced by the Spider entering with 2 counters. Both Doubling Season and Hardened Scales can replace Graft and each other, so you choose which to apply first.

616.1. If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object’s controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply, following the steps listed below. [..]
616.1f Once the chosen effect has been applied, this process is repeated (taking into account only replacement or prevention effects that would now be applicable) until there are no more left to apply.

If you apply DS first, you get (2*2)+1 = 5 counters, and if you apply HS first, you get (2+1)*2 = 6 counters.
